# How do I convert a List<interface> to List<concrete>?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an interface defined as:

```
public interface MyInterface {
     object foo { get; set; };
}
```

and a class that implements that interface:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface {
     object foo { get; set; }
}
```

I then create a function that returns a ICollection like so:

```
public ICollection<MyClass> Classes() {
    List<MyClass> value;

    List<MyInterface> list = new List<MyInterface>(
        new MyInterface[] {
            new MyClass {
                ID = 1
            },
            new MyClass {
                ID = 1
            },
            new MyClass {
                ID = 1
            }
        });

    value = new List<MyClass>((IEnumerable<MyClass>) list);

    return value;
}
```

It would compile but would throw a

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyInterface]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyClass]'.

exception.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A `List<MyInterface>` cannot be converted to a `List<MyClass>` in general, because the first list might contain objects that implement `MyInterface` but which aren't actually objects of type `MyClass`.

However, since in your case you know how you constructed the list and can be sure that it contains only `MyClass` objects, you can do this using Linq:

```
return list.ConvertAll(o => (MyClass)o);
```

Comment: This will work in .Net 2.0+ and not just LINQ as System.Collections.Generic.List<> supports ConvertAll<T>() directly.

Comment: Thanks, @Ritch. I thought that `ConvertAll` was a Linq method, but I hadn't bothered to check.

Comment: Actually, if you are sure that your list contains only `MyClass` objects, you should use `Enumerable.Cast<TResult>` Method, and you will get an `InvalidCastException` if an element in the sequence cannot be cast to `MyClass`.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: Thanks - your method saved a lot of effort. I am using telerik wpf components and in the RadDataFilter the return value is a list of interfaces and I have to do a long foreach with typecasting and string match switches and if else. Now I can use linq. :)

Answer (score 37):

But a `List<MyInterface>` is emphatically not a `List<MyClass>`.

Think:

```
interface IAnimal { }

class Cat : IAnimal { }
class Dog : IAnimal { }

var list = new List<IAnimal> { new Cat(), new Dog() };
```

Then

```
var cats = (List<Cat>)list;
```

Absurd!

Also,

```
var cats = list.Cast<Cat>();
```

Absurd!

Further

```
var cats = list.ConvertAll(x => (Cat)x);
```

Absurd!

Instead, you could say

```
var cats = list.OfType<Cat>();
```

Comment: I see. I was confused because you can cast an interface to its concrete class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Cast<>` extension method:

```
return list.Cast<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Can you add some details?

Answer (score 0):

I find Automapper very useful for converting interfaces to concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and that's where the generics shine!
Here is a simple example:

```
public interface ICountable
{
     int Count { get; set; }
}

public class PopularName : ICountable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class PopularSize : ICountable
{
     public int Size { get; set; }
     public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And now you need to declare your method (or your class) generic like this:

```
public bool HasAnyValue<T>(List<T> countableModel) where T : ICountable
{
    return countableModel.Count > 0;
}
```