# Create generic filter of IQueryable<T> where the filter uses property defined in ISomeInterface

Tags: c#, linq, generics, multi-tenant, iqueryable

I am implementing a custom processing pipeline for a multi-tenant web API. This creates a requirement where the last step of the data retrieval pipeline must be ensuring, that only data specific to a given tenant is returned to the caller, which I thought would be best done using a

For data retrieval, the process looks like this:

- HTTP call hits the thin controller, where it's resolved to a CQS-compliant query and passed to the mediator for handling
- mediator is configured to feed all requests through the pipeline, which has a few steps

  1. Validation
  2. Caching
  3. Any Query specific Pre handlers
  4. Handling the Query in the handler (returns `IQueryable<TEntity>`)
  5. Any Query specific Post handlers
  6. Returning to the caller (returns `IQueryable<TEntity>`)

My domain model has a bunch of classes, which inherit from a base class that is decorated with a simple IMultitenantEntity interface.

```cs
public interface IMultitenantEntity
{
    long TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

My idea was to inject another Post handler, specific to all pipeline requests which return `IQueryable<TEntity>` where `TEntity` implements `IMultitenantEntity` interface. Simple enough, I can't get it to work due to casting/type issues. I am sure that my mind just got stuck in an infinite loop of dumb ideas and I need someone to please get me out of this loop, thank you very much :)

Here is my Post handler as it is right now:

```cs
public interface IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse>
{
    Task Handle(ref TResponse response);
}

public class PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<TResponse> : IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse>
    where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>
{
    public Task Handle(ref TResponse response)
    {
response = (TResponse)response.Where(t => t.TenantId == 1);
        return Task.FromResult(1);
    }
}
```

Now imagine, that the a request comes through the pipeline and the query handler returns IQueryable. Not surprisingly, once we hit the above handler, we get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '`System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[IMultitenantEntity]`'
>   to type
>   '`System.Linq.IQueryable'1[Game]`'.

If we debug the `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler.Handle()` method, we can see that TResponse is of `IQueryable<Game>` as intended, but to be able to include the `Where(t => t.TenantId == 1)` part, I added `where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>`, and this causes the result of the LINQ `Where()` to be of the `IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>` type, which is much more generic than `IQueryable<Game>`, hence it's not possible to cast from `IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>` to `IQueryable<Game>`... and here is where I am stuck in my infinite mind loop.

Help! :)

**EDIT:**

I was able to wire the pipeline to use the following:

```cs
public class PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<TResponse, TEntity> : IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse, TEntity>
        where TResponse : IQueryable<TEntity>
        where TEntity : IMultitenantEntity
```

which enabled the possibility of

```cs
var intermediary = response.Where(t => t.TenantId == 1).Cast<TEntity>();
```

but it's still not enough, on

```cs
response = (TResponse)intermediary;
```

same I get same old

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '`System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[IMultitenantEntity]`'
>   to type
>   '`System.Linq.IQueryable'1[Game]`'.

What should I do so that the `TResponse` type is not scaled down to `IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>` but I would still be able to add the missing WHERE predicate?

**EDIT 2:**

So the real limitation here is that the calling method lives within the class which does not know anything about the `TEntity` as a separate type.

When I said, that the a request comes through the pipeline and the query handler returns IQueryable it was not detailed enough. The thing is, the pipeline is capable of processing query handlers which can have any return types, not only `IQueryable<T>`. So what the pipeline knows is the type of the request (a query that's feeded through it) and the type of the response to a handled request. So when I wired the `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<TResponse, TEntity>` in the pipeline, `TEntity` was always `IMultitenantEntity`, which is back to square one - `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler` does not know the concrete type of `TEntity` and the pipeline is not capable of providing it.

What we know is a concrete type of `TResponse` and that it implements `IQueryable'.

Long story short, I am still looking for a way to add the `.Where(t => t.TenantId == 1)` filter to the response. Thoughts, anyone?

**EDIT 3:**

So that everything is super-clear, I thought it would be benefitial to provide a little bit of background about how `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler` is called.

As mentioned before, all requests are feeded through a common processing pipeline (separate async na sync implementations are available). The pipeline class signature is as follows:

```
public class AsyncMediatorPipeline<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IAsyncRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IAsyncRequest<TResponse>
```

and the constructor, as it is now:

public AsyncMediatorPipeline(
            IAsyncRequestHandler inner,
            IAsyncPreRequestHandler[] preRequestHandlers,
            IAsyncPostRequestHandler[] postRequestHandlers,
            IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler[] postQueryableRequestHandlers
            )

all constructor parameters are injected with AutoFac, the `IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<,>` is configured as:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<,>))
  .As(typeof(IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<,>))
  .SingleInstance();
```

The pipeline class handles all requests in its own `Handle` method:

```
public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest message)
{
    // PRE handlers
    foreach (var preRequestHandler in _preRequestHandlers)
    {
        await preRequestHandler.Handle(message);
    }

    // Request handler (this one is also decorated with additional pipeline, where all cross-cutting concerns such as validation, caching, requests logging etc. are handled
    var result = await _inner.Handle(message);

    // Our stubborn IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity> compatibile Where() filter handler
    foreach (var postQueryableRequestHandler in _postQueryableRequestHandlers)
    {
        await postQueryableRequestHandler.Handle(ref result);
    }

    // POST handlers
    foreach (var postRequestHandler in _postRequestHandlers)
    {
        await postRequestHandler.Handle(message, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have two separate "post" handlers, because generic "post" handler does not allow to manipulate the response

```
public interface IAsyncPostRequestHandler<in TRequest, in TResponse>
{
    Task Handle(TRequest request, TResponse response);
}
```

whereas the Queryable one does

```
public interface IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse, in TEntity>
{
    Task Handle(ref TResponse response);
}
```

Hopefully this sheds a little bit more light on the issue.

Comment: can `response.Where(t => t.TenantId == 1).Cast<TResponse>()` work for you?

Comment: It will not work, unfortunately, because you would then have `DbQuery<IQueryable<Game>>` and it's not castable (not surprisingly) to `IQueryable<Game>`

Comment: Yes, I didn't paid attention to it. is there any possiblity to use something like `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<IQueryable<TResponse>>`?

Comment: I've tried `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<TResponse, TEntity>` with `where TResponse : IQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : IMultitenantEntity` and I have issues with injecting it into my main mediator pipeline, since it's also generic and it handles all requests (not only the ones which return `IQueryable<T>`) so I guess without any knowledge of T it just cannot match the class during injection. I am still researching it.

Comment: if you have added constraint `where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>` then using `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<IQueryable<TResponse>>` should not be any problem, but your situation seems a bit complex, and I cannot say something certainly beacause I am not aware of lots of things in your program and requirements.

Comment: I added an edit in the original issue description, it is closer to what you suggested, perhaps it would allow us to move forward with the final resolution. Please take a look when you have time, thanks!

Comment: With the update you are almost there. All you need now is to add `class` constraint, e.g. `where TEntity : class, IMultitenantEntity`. And remove `Cast` call.

Comment: @IvanStoev, adding the `class` constraint on TEntity and removing `Cast<>()` still unfortunately causes the same exception as mentioned in the edit above.

Comment: Something is wrong then. If you look at the generic arguments of the method (when called), they should be `TResponse = IQueryable<Game>` and `TEntity = Game`, right? Then when you say `var intermediary = response.Where(t => t.TenantId == 1);`, the type of the `intermediary` variable should be `IQueryable<Game>`.

Comment: Silly me... `TEntity = IMultitenantEntity`. Calling class where `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler` is injected knows `TResponse = IQueryable<TEntity>`, but it does not know and cannot know `TEntity`, because `TResponse` itself can be of any type. `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler` is called only when the `TResponse` type matches `IQueryable<TEntity>` and the entity iself must support multi-tenancy by implementing `IMultitenantEntity`. So `PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler` will receive a correct `TResponse=IQueryable<Game>' but it cannot have <TEntity=Game>'. Any hints how to approach this?

Comment: @IvanStoev adding `class` constraint makes it work in simple scenario. It is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you always filter for `TenantId == 1`? Are you ok if the solution contains a bit more code? It is also interesting to me, so I have reserched and found solution. I just want to be certain about some things before posting it as answer. We can also talk via email if it is convenient for you.

Comment: @AdilMammadov, please reach out to me on Skype, my user handle is sebastianzaklada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I'm afraid you have to resort to manual non generic expression/query building.

For instance, something like this should do the trick:

```
public interface IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse>
{
    Task Handle(ref TResponse response);
}

public class PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<TResponse> : IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse>
    where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>
{
    public Task Handle(ref TResponse response)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(response.ElementType, "t");
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(parameter, "TenantId"),
                Expression.Constant(1)),
            parameter);
        var whereCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] { parameter.Type },
            response.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));
        response = (TResponse)response.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCall);
        return Task.FromResult(1);
    }
}
```

The key point is that you can get the actual `TEntity` type from the passed  `IQueryable` (`ElementType` property), but since you can't use it to call generic methods (because all you have is a `Type` object), you have to compose both `Where` predicate and the `Where` call using the presented non generic techniques.

**Update:** Here is another more elegant (although most likely slower) solution based on dynamic dispatch feature:

```
public interface IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse>
{
    Task Handle(ref TResponse response);
}

public class PostTenantQueryableFilterHandler<TResponse> : IAsyncQueryablePostRequestHandler<TResponse>
    where TResponse : IQueryable<IMultitenantEntity>
{
    public Task Handle(ref TResponse response)
    {
        response = PostTenantQueryableFilter.Handle((dynamic)response);
        return Task.FromResult(1);
    }
}

static class PostTenantQueryableFilter
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Handle<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> response)
        where TEntity : class, IMultitenantEntity
    {
        return response.Where(t => t.TenantId == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I also suggested the same solution yesterday :)

Comment: @AdilMammadov Yeah. Not the most elegant code, but is working and is sort of type safe. Another option is to get the element type and dispatch a reflection or dynamic call to another generic method with the correct generic type arguments, but that also is not so natural. As you mentioned in the comments, the best is  if OP can replace `TResponse` argument with `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

Comment: It looks like I was very close to resolving it myself, I wrote a very similar piece of code that had one bug in it and hence did not work out of the box and I abandoned it for a while thinking, that there must be a better solution to the problem. Looks like there is not and I am very grateful for your help Ivan and @AdilMammadov

Comment: You are welcome @Sebastian. Glad to help, and good luck with what are you doing.

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides a usefull information as well as the reason why this is not working:

[Casting list of interface to concrete typed list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019805)

Basically the problem here is that you cannot casts a list of a interface to a list of a concrete type. If the result wasn't a list, but a single object you would be able to cast it. In this case you have to cast each one and return the new collection either with thw `Cast<TResponse>()` or with the `ConvertAll<TResponse>()` Method.

Comment: Yup. I know why it does not work, I am trying to find a way so that my logic could be implemented, and I know that I would need a different approach. I just posted what I was trying to do before I realized that (famous quote warning) "it's a trap!"