# Convert ICollection<Interface> to ICollection<Class> [UWP] c#6.0

Tags: c#, interface, uwp

I know this has been answered a lot of places on stack and the best possible answer is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019812/3766231). I've tried it and a lot of other answers too. I have a library that returns me a collection of an Interface (`IMasterAutoSuggestOutlet`)

```
public interface IMasterAutoSuggestOutlet : IBaseAutoSuggestOutlet
{
    IAddressData AddressData { get; }

    IPlaceActivity PlaceActivity { get; }

    string ELoc { get; }

    Geopoint ExactLocation { get; }

    Geopoint EntranceLocation { get; }

    LocationType TypeOfLocation { get; }
}
```

Now, I want to transfer this interface data from one page to another in my application. Since Interfaces cannot be serialized, I created a concrete class that implements this interface:

My Concrete Class,

```
public class MasterAutoSuggestModel : IMasterAutoSuggestOutlet
{
    public IAddressData AddressData { get; set; }

    public IPlaceActivity PlaceActivity { get; set; }

    public string ELoc { get; set; }

    public Geopoint ExactLocation { get; set; }

    public Geopoint EntranceLocation { get; set; }

    public LocationType TypeOfLocation { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is, convert the ICollection to ICollection. My code below shows my implementation of such an operation:

```
var collection = mainPageViewModel?.SearchPageVM?.searchManager?.AutoSuggestResponse;
var ob = collection.First();
if (ob is IMasterAutoSuggestOutlet)
{
    var ToBeTransfered = collection.OfType<MasterAutoSuggestModel>();    //Simply returns the collection with a count 0
    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ToBeTransfered);
    ScenarioFrame.Navigate(typeof(MasterSearchResultPage), serializedData);
}
```

The issue is with `var ToBeTransfered = col.OfType<MasterAutoSuggestModel>();` it returns me a collection with count 0 even though the `collection` has 10 items in it.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong? Please note I need to use this Converted collection to serialize and send as the navigation parameter to send to the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ofType method filters the connection by the type specified. If you are retrieving the objects from some other library, they would not be that specific type.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx

What you would probably want to do is convert the items retrieved from the library into your dto for serialisation. You can use something like automapper for the conversion

```
if (ob is IMasterAutoSuggestOutlet) {
   var transferObject = new MasterAutoSuggestModel(){
       //Set Properties
    }
   // var ToBeTransfered = collection.OfType<MasterAutoSuggestModel>();    //Simply returns the collection with a count 0
    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transferObject);
    ScenarioFrame.Navigate(typeof(MasterSearchResultPage), serializedData); }
```

Comment: I am not sure that manually setting properties is the right approach, because in this case the properties are alot less but what happens when there are more than just 6 properties?

Comment: That's where something like AutoMapper comes in

Comment: Is there any way around installing the automapper nugget or importing the libraries and do a map. Is there an explicit cast I can do? Or write an extension method for the same?

Comment: you could only cast it to the concrete type, if you have access to the concrete type in the library. As the library is returning an interface, casting is not the way to go as actual implementation type could change, and therefore breaking your code.

Comment: Okay so do you have an example on how can I use autoMapper in this case? I am failing miserably to use automapper to convert the Interface to class.